# Unable to hide subcategories in category blog layout

Tags: joomla-3.x, com-content, category, configuration, subcategories

I have a menu item of the `category blog` type, which is pointing to a category which has category children. I have configured this menu item and the category manager options to hide all subcategories, as shown in the images below, ie. **subcategory levels = none**.

To my knowledge, these settings are supposed to hide all child categories from a blog page, **but my category blog page displays all of the articles** from the child categories as well as those from the parent category.

I have some overrides in place for `blog.php` and `blog_item.php` but temporarily removing these had no impact on my problem.

What I want is to hide the articles from any child category, only displaying articles in the top (parent) category.

So my question is, why are the configuration settings not working the way I intend? What could be causing this issue?

#### Menu - Category Blog - config options

[image: Menu - Category Blog - config options]

#### Category Manager - config options

[image: Category Manager - config options]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Menu - Category Blog - Blog layout options

Did you check this setting too ? in the menu options ?

[image: Joomla category blog layout options]

Answer (score 4):

As @Sasi varna kumar showed with the screenshot in his answer, what you need to adjust is what articles should be shown in your blog layout.

The settings you were adjusting are about showing categories and subcategories, which (the categories) can be considered as an independent content entity. Showing categories's data, like category's and subcategories' text, descriptions, images etc, should not be confused with showing articles from these categories.

And what articles should be displayed are handled in the "**Blog Layout**" tab.